# Text substitution inside compressed files

Tags: sed, zip

I have several zip files, each one having several text files inside them.
I want to substitute all occurrences of `a` in these text files with `b`, and leave them zipped with the same structure.

If I just wanted to find the occurrences of `a`, I know I could use the [`zgrep`](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_zgrep.htm) command, but I also want to perform string substitution. Unfortunately, there is no `zsed` command.

Do I have no choice but to write a script with a loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to change the text in the files in a zip file, then you have no choice but extract them, edit them and re-add them.

If you need this done on the larger part of the contents of the `.zip` (not by number of files, but total compressed amount), it is easier to extract everything to a new directory, edit the relevant files and zip everything. This is e.g. the case when editing all the `.html` files in a `.epub` and leaving the metadata the same, as re-zipping metadata takes minimal time compared to the rest of the data.

Comment: Thanks, but I didn't understand your example: if the only way is to extract everything, edit and compress again, then what do you mean by "it is easier"? Easier than what?

Comment: You can also just extract the filenames that have text to change in them. But if those files are just e.g. 1% of the size of the total .zip, recompressing the rest is prohibitive. In that case just extract those file and add them again.

Comment: I see. So the suggestion in the first paragraph of your answer is to manipulate only the relevant files, not extract all the files and re-add everything to a new zip.

Comment: @DanielHershcovich Exactly that was my suggestion. The first might be faster because you don't recompress everything, but is slower because you have to decompress at least the matching files twice (once doing the zgrep, and then extracting the matching files). So it really depends on the whole of the .zip what is more efficient. (And if this is something you only do once, that is probably not important at all)

Comment: You don't need to extract and rebuild the zip. You can use fuse-zip to manipulate the zip content as a directory.

Answer (score 8):

You can work on a mount of a zip file to a directory, after which you can explore and modify it as if it was a directory.

Install [fuse-zip](https://bitbucket.org/agalanin/fuse-zip/) (available via the package manager in all good distributions).

```bash
mount_point=$(TMPDIR=$PWD mktemp -d)
# Iterate over the .zip files in the current directory
for z in *.zip; do
  fuse-zip "$z" "$mount_point"
  # At this point, the zip contents are available through the mount point
  find "$mount_point" -type f -exec sed -i 's/a/b/g' {} +
  fusermount -u "$mount_point"
done
rmdir "$mount_point"
```

(**Note**: I assume GNU sed syntax in this example.)